# Modals and Forms

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog

So the part of my code that has an issue is as follows

```js
var manuSu = document.getElementById("Man");

manuSu.onclick = function(){
   for(i=0; i<8;i++){
     periodEnd[i] = document.getElementById("pE").elements.item(i).value;
   }
   modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

"Man" is a button and "pE" is a form. I have run the code in chrome and get the error

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null(…)

I have done about 30 min of googling and apparently it has something to do with the modal. Both the form and button are contained in the modal

**Edit:**
Unless you've previously declared the `i` variable from your `for` loop in a containing scope, realize that you would be declaring a global variable (a poor practice).

Comment: Please show the html code where you define the "Man" button.

Comment: manuSu is ``null``, meaning the ``document.getElementById`` found nothing when looking for that ``id`` and had to ``return`` null.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `<div id="Man"></div>` don't exist in that moment, then this code executes. Just run it AFTER you display your modal, then `<div id="Man"></div>` be in DOM.

Also you can use jQuery-framework, there you can attach event-listeners on object which don't exist in that moment, but can appear later.

Comment: Can you provide me with an example of the event listener or a resource to learn it. I dont know much about jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to diagnose the error based on only what you have provided. However, based on Chrome's thrown error, one possible issue I could think of has to do with `<script>` loading. For example, if you didn't wrap your code in a `window.onload` event listener (or its jQuery equivalent, `$(document).ready()`), you are prone to encountering issues such as what you are encountering. The issue stems from the fact that the DOM hasn't yet been fully parsed/rendered before your function executes. Thus, when it looks for something with an `id` attribute of `#Man`, it returns `null` because no such element has yet been appended to the DOM. The `onload` (or `ready`) event handlers obviate this issue by deferring your script's execution until the DOM has been fully rendered. To this end, it could also prove helpful to move your `<script>` tag containing your function such that it is the last element before the `<body>` element's closing tag (`</body>`). Because the HTML page is read linearly (*i.e.*, left-to-right, top-to-bottom), delegating a `<script>` to this position in the HTML page means it will not be hit until the entirety of `document.body` has been rendered and displayed.